# Gradle desktop launcher failing to detect platform

Tags: android-studio, gradle, android-gradle-plugin, lwjgl, glfw

I'm working on a gradle/libGDX project. I've been able to build it as a web app in the past, but that step failed on the current version. I tried using the desktop launcher to troubleshoot and that is also failing.

It runs when compiled through Android Studio. It also seems like maybe it's building successfully but failing afterwards. I'm running this on WSL. I tried it on a different machine with a similar WSL/Android studio setup and I get the same result.

The error when trying to run `./gradlew desktop:run`

```
[LWJGL] GLFW_PLATFORM_UNAVAILABLE error
        Description : Failed to detect any supported platform
        Stacktrace  :
                org.lwjgl.glfw.GLFW.glfwInit(GLFW.java:1047)
                com.badlogic.gdx.backends.lwjgl3.Lwjgl3Application.initializeGlfw(Lwjgl3Application.java:88)
                com.badlogic.gdx.backends.lwjgl3.Lwjgl3Application.<init>(Lwjgl3Application.java:138)
                com.mygdx.vdna.DesktopLauncher.main(DesktopLauncher.java:12)
Exception in thread "main" com.badlogic.gdx.utils.GdxRuntimeException: Unable to initialize GLFW
        at com.badlogic.gdx.backends.lwjgl3.Lwjgl3Application.initializeGlfw(Lwjgl3Application.java:89)
        at com.badlogic.gdx.backends.lwjgl3.Lwjgl3Application.<init>(Lwjgl3Application.java:138)
        at com.mygdx.vdna.DesktopLauncher.main(DesktopLauncher.java:12)
```

The DesktopLauncher code at the start of the error is:

```
package com.mygdx.vdna;

import com.badlogic.gdx.backends.lwjgl3.Lwjgl3Application;
import com.badlogic.gdx.backends.lwjgl3.Lwjgl3ApplicationConfiguration;

public class DesktopLauncher {
    public static void main (String[] arg) {
        Lwjgl3ApplicationConfiguration config = new Lwjgl3ApplicationConfiguration();
        config.setWindowedMode(800, 480);
        config.useVsync(true);
        config.setForegroundFPS(60);
        new Lwjgl3Application(new com.mygdx.vdna.VGame(), config);
    }
}
```

When I run gradle build, I get a different, potentially informative error:

```
WARNING:We recommend using a newer Android Gradle plugin to use compileSdk = 33

This Android Gradle plugin (7.2.1) was tested up to compileSdk = 32

This warning can be suppressed by adding
    android.suppressUnsupportedCompileSdk=33
to this project's gradle.properties

The build will continue, but you are strongly encouraged to update your project to
use a newer Android Gradle Plugin that has been tested with compileSdk = 33
Checking the license for package Android SDK Build-Tools 33 in /mnt/c/Users/Narthan/AppData/Local/Android/Sdk/licenses
License for package Android SDK Build-Tools 33 accepted.
Preparing "Install Android SDK Build-Tools 33 (revision: 33.0.0)".

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
'void org.apache.commons.compress.archivers.zip.ZipFile.<init>(java.nio.channels.SeekableByteChannel)'

* Try:
> Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
> Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
> Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 2s
```

I tried re-installing the Android SDK using the SDK manager in android studio and get this error

```
Packages to install: - Android SDK Build-Tools 33 (build-tools;33.0.0)


Preparing "Install Android SDK Build-Tools 33 (revision: 33.0.0)".
Found existing prepared package.
"Install Android SDK Build-Tools 33 (revision: 33.0.0)" ready.
An error occurred during installation: C:\mnt\c\Users\Narthan\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\.temp\PackageOperation01\unzip.
"Install Android SDK Build-Tools 33 (revision: 33.0.0)" complete.
"Install Android SDK Build-Tools 33 (revision: 33.0.0)" failed.
Failed packages:
- Android SDK Build-Tools 33 (build-tools;33.0.0)
```

my `local.properties` (where that path location is from) is yellow in android studio, but I don't notice anything wrong with it. The path exists and is empty.

Any suggestions about what to try next? My current suspiscion is that I damaged and important gradle file. I'm still learning about gradle project organization.

Comment: This is a GLFW issue and has nothing to do with Gradle. Probably GLFW has trouble finding the desktop in WSL? GLFW is the game window library used by LWJGL3.  I don't have any linux experience, so can't help with that.

Comment: Most probably, WSL causes this error. You can read more about this specific GLFW error here: https://www.glfw.org/docs/3.4/group__errors.html#ga3608c6c29ab7a72f3bf019f4c3a2563d and search for "glfw wsl" in Google (it'll show that running GLFW on WSL is a common issue)